# Setting up NHibernate Velocity Cache on Azure

Tags: nhibernate, azure, appfabric

I am attempting to set up 2nd level caching for NHibernate 3.2 with Windows Azure Caching. So far,  using https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/, I have setup Azure caching in my web.config :

```
<section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
...
<dataCacheClients>
 <dataCacheClient name="default">
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="App.UI" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

I then downloaded and added the Velocity cache provider DLLs from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Caches/3.2.0.GA_for_NH3.2.0GA/

Finally, my hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
    ...
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache" >true</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.Velocity.VelocityProvider, NHibernate.Caches.Velocity</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**UPDATE**
Solved, the dependency issue, I now get an error 
{"ErrorCode:\"dcacheClient\" tag not specified in the application configuration file. Specify valid tag in configuration file."}

Thank you